# How to boot up a vmware ESXi 6.7 virtual machine that doesn't boot due to lack of space?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vmdk, vsphere

I have a VMWare ESXi 6.7 cluster configured by some I.T tech that cannot by now assist us, but I have an urgent needing of solving this boot up problem. The virtual machine doesn't finish booting up,  claiming lack of space, saying specifically - "There is no more space for virtual disk 'FICHEIROS_1.vmdk'. You might be able to continue this session by freeing disk space on the relevant volume, and clicking Retry. Click Cancel to terminate this session."

when I try to extend the virtual machine virtual disk space, it notifies me with the message - "A general system error occurred: Resource temporarily unavailable".

I've made a research and found out it may be due to one the virtual machines locking a file needed to make changes to the virtual machine's settings that doesn't boot up.

On VMWare's support site, I followed instructions there saying I should from vsphere web client, reset the notifications to green, later click on Unlock VM. The problem is that I can't find the button - Unlock VM.

It's a cluster with 2 nodes, three DELL servers one PowerEdge R820 as Witness, and Two PowerEdge R710 with RAID 0, 4 SAS disks each with 300 GB.

VMWare site I'm referring here is https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.7/com.vmware.vsphere.security.doc/GUID-CB459722-C7B6-4EA3-B8D3-EB44BCF23077.html

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem was related with a faulting disk in the cluster, dispite I could not still find the missing button - Unlock VM to try the approach mentioned on VMWare website. After replacing the faulting disk it worked fine.